# Python: Refresh PivotTables in worksheet

Tags: python, excel, ms-office, excel-2010, win32com

I'm building a python script that will allow me to open a Excel 2010 worksheet and print it out.

I got most of the way

```
import win32com.client

office = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
wb = office.Workbooks.Open(r"path\to\excel\file\to\print.xlsm")

count = wb.Sheets.Count
for i in range(count):
    ws = wb.Worksheets[i]

    pivotCount = ws.PivotTables().Count
    for j in range(1, pivotCount+1):
        #TODO code to refresh each pivot table

    ws.PrintOut()
    print "Worksheet: %s - has been sent to the printer" % (ws.Name)
```

As you can see I'm still missing the refreshing of the pivot tables in the worksheet.

The VBA code for refreshing is:

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1).PivotCache.Refresh
```

I can't seem to break the code into python win32com syntax. The closest I got is:

```
wb.WorkSheets(5).PivotTables(1).PivotCache.Refresh
```

which gives `<bound method CDispatch.Refresh of <COMObject PivotCache>>` but no result in the the worksheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found my problem. I had a protection on the worksheet. Here is the solution:

```
import win32com.client

office = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
wb = office.Workbooks.Open(r"path\to\excel\file\to\print.xlsm")

count = wb.Sheets.Count
for i in range(count):
    ws = wb.Worksheets[i]
    ws.Unprotect() # IF protected

    pivotCount = ws.PivotTables().Count
    for j in range(1, pivotCount+1):
        ws.PivotTables(j).PivotCache().Refresh()

    # Put protection back on
    ws.Protect(DrawingObjects=True, Contents=True, Scenarios=True, AllowUsingPivotTables=True)

    ws.PrintOut()
    print "Worksheet: %s - has been sent to the printer" % (ws.Name)
```